# My gravatar stopped working on most of stack exchange

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

Upon visiting Meta Stack Exchange today, I noticed that my gravatar had been replaced with the default geometric art image.

Upon further research, it appears that it is still there on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294423/gavin-s-yancey), [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1294423/gavin-s-yancey), and [my "network profile" page](https://stackexchange.com/users/1356059/g-rocket?tab=accounts), but seems to be gone [every](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28452/)[where](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10894/) [else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56043/) [on](https://serverfault.com/users/222121/gavin-s-yancey) [Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/243717/gavin-s-yancey).

I used to have this same gravatar on all Stack Exchange sites.  What caused it to stop working?  How can I get it back?

Comment: I had the same case, I worked it around by downloading from gravatar and uploading to SE profile. I thought the source was my work environment

Comment: If you're using gravatar then you're in the rollercoaster of working and broken profile images, either for all, or per region, partially loading, only specific sizes that work, different patterns that get generated all of a sudden. Possible causes are moon phases, weather, extra-terrestrial noise. Do what Tensibai suggests.

Comment: Update on this: I changed it back to "source: Gravitar" on MSE and that stuck, but the "copy changes to other sites" button didn't seem to do anything.  I suspect this is exactly the same issue as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345627/243717